# Regex: Ignore punctuation when selecting part of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a way to select a part of a string with punctuation based on a string that doesn't have punctuation.

Ex.

> Oh, my goodness. This is it. Oh.

I want to select `Oh, my goodness.` (note the trailing period). The string that I have to search with is:

> oh my goodness

I've been looking all around for a solution to this, but I can't seem to find a good answer. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question lacks some details, so here are some assumptions:

- your space separated search term is a sequence of words to find, e.g. search term `foo bar` will not find `some bar foo text` input
- your search term should ignore non-word chars, for example `foo bar` will find `some foo, bar text` and `some foo: bar text`
- you want to find the search term anywhere in the input
- include a trailing dot, if any (e.g. not required)

The regex can be tweaked as needed if some of the assumptions are not correct.

Code with match and replace examples:

```js
const input = 'Oh, my goodness. This is it. Oh.';
const searchTerm = 'oh my goodness';

const regex = new RegExp('\\b' + searchTerm.replace(/ +/g, '\\W+') + '\.?', 'i');
console.log({
  match: input.match(regex),
  replace: input.replace(regex, '<b>$&</b>')
});
```

Output:

```
{
  "match": [
    "Oh, my goodness."
  ],
  "replace": "<b>Oh, my goodness.</b> This is it. Oh."
}
```

Explanation of regex construct:

- `'\\b'` -- word boundary (replace with `'^'` if you want to search at the beginning of the input string)
- `searchTerm.replace(/ +/g, '\\W+')` -- allow any non-word chars, such as `,`, `:`
- `'\.?'` -- include optional dot
- `'i'` -- regex flag to ignore case

Comment: This is precisely what I needed, thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

`/[^.]*\b(oh|my)\b.(?=goodness)[^.]*\./Ug`

- `[^.]*` and `[^.]*` check the start and the end of a sentence
- `\b(oh|my)\b.` matches words **oh** and **my** in a sentence
- `(?=goodness)` is a **positive lookahead**. We tell the regex: '*Search **oh** and **my** words before the word **goodness***'
- also, we use `g` (global) and `U` (Ungreedy) regex flags.

In short, the regex will match all the sentences containing mentioned words and will separate the given line into matching sentences.

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cF7Mb8/1)

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but I guess it's because you haven't explained anything. Plus, I've tested it with Regexr and it selects way too much. For example if in the sentence after oh my goodness comes another `my` it selects that as well.

Comment: @GuidoVisser can you check the regex now? I am adding comments right now.

Comment: maybe check it yourself before posting, because this selects way too much again. Go to https://regexr.com and add `Oh, my goodness.` to the block of text, somewhere in the middle and put your solution in there. It selects way too much in front of it.

Comment: @GuidoVisser Actually, I check my answers before posting. Maybe I don't have enough tests to check. Sorry. By the way, I am trying to help you.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I truly appreciate it, but the answer doesn't solve my problem unfortunately.